# DDD solution structure

Tags: c#, mongodb, repository, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I'm trying to create a nice a Solution structure for a new DDD project. I Created a "Core" project, where I added the Entities, ValueObjects and the repositories Interfaces then I added an "Infrastructure" project that contains the implementation of the previous IRepository.

Now, since my db will be MongoDb I need to add the attributes like "[BsonDateTimeOptions]" in some of the fields of the Entities, this will require to add a reference to the MongoDb driver package in the core project.

Since the core project should not contains any reference to MongoDb, should only contains business logic and it should be reusable in any other project (mobile - Xamarin) what should be the best practice in this situation?

What I'm able to think is:

- the entities will not contains any reference to MongoDb
- create in the Infrastructure projects a model for each Entity, that is a copy of the related entity but with the MongoDb attributes.
- create a layer (in the repository?) that is able to use the model to query in the db, then transform it in entity and so returning the Entity, hiding inside the repository the model object.

This approach has a problem, that I will have a copy of the entity, the model, which only has the MongoDb attributes, and when adding some fields to an entity, I will have to modify the model too. Is this the correct approach?

Everything started from [this](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture) solution structure.

Comment: What i would do is to make 2 different copies of the entities as you said. One for the database and one for the actual entity. I would also use some kind of Interface that will hold the properties of my entities by doing that you would only need to update the interface and then you could use autopopulate to make the changes in the models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using attributes in your domain classes, write configuration code in the Infrastructure layer.

This seems to always be an option with MongoDB.NET, e.g.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm => 
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapMember(c => c.DateOfBirth).SetSerializer(new DateTimeSerializer(dateOnly: true));
}
```

instead of

```
[BsonDateTimeOptions(DateOnly = true)]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Comment: I think that this is exactly what I was searching for. I'm going to try to implement it this way right now

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I don't use C# but this works in PHP and maybe  it helps you*

They way I do it is to create the Aggregate root, nested entities and Value objects as plain objects (data + behavior, without any dependency to infrastructure/technology). Then, when persisting/rehydrating I use reflection to store/load the Aggregates from the Repository. The Repository is mapping any known domain objects to infrastructure objects. For example, the primitive types (string, bool, int, float, null) are stored without any transformation. The [Date](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.datetimeimmutable.php) is transformed to [ISODate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date), the Guid is transformed to [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) and so on.

This is possible because of reflection and easy because MongoDB is storing objects as JSON and there is little (or none) impedance mismatch.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was thinking about. But what @guillaume31 posted should be (I need to try it out) what I was searching for, anyway I'll upvote this since if the driver did not offer that syntax, I should have choose this road.

Comment: @DavideQuaglio but you have to write a lot of boiler plate code. I like generic solutions.

Comment: I think I will be using some reflection to reduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the approach you describe is correct, but what you call a layer in repo, would be just an adapter in the infrastructure layer. The adapter implements the repo interface using mongodb technology, and use a mapper to convert between the two models. The mapper belongs to the infraestructure layer too.